# Searching for different places with the Google Maps API

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-places-api

I'm creating a page to search for various places on the Google map. I started with the code provided by google ( https://developers-dot-devsite-v2-prod.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete-hotelsearch ) and i have test the code with JSFiddle :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Place Autocomplete Hotel Search</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <style>
      /* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
       * element that contains the map. */
      #map {
        height: 100%;
      }
      /* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */
      html, body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
      body {
        padding: 0 !important;
      }
      table {
        font-size: 12px;
      }
      .hotel-search {
        -webkit-box-align: center;
        -ms-flex-align: center;
        align-items: center;
        background: #fff;
        display: -webkit-box;
        display: -ms-flexbox;
        display: flex;
        left: 0;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        width: 440px;
        z-index: 1;
      }
      #map {
        margin-top: 40px;
        width: 440px;
      }
      #listing {
        position: absolute;
        width: 200px;
        height: 470px;
        overflow: auto;
        left: 442px;
        top: 0px;
        cursor: pointer;
        overflow-x: hidden;
      }
      #findhotels {
        font-size: 14px;
      }
      #locationField {
        -webkit-box-flex: 1 1 190px;
        -ms-flex: 1 1 190px;
        flex: 1 1 190px;
        margin: 0 8px;
      }
      #controls {
        -webkit-box-flex: 1 1 140px;
        -ms-flex: 1 1 140px;
        flex: 1 1 140px;
      }
      #autocomplete {
        width: 100%;
      }
      #country {
        width: 100%;
      }
      .placeIcon {
        width: 20px;
        height: 34px;
        margin: 4px;
      }
      .hotelIcon {
        width: 24px;
        height: 24px;
      }
      #resultsTable {
        border-collapse: collapse;
        width: 240px;
      }
      #rating {
        font-size: 13px;
        font-family: Arial Unicode MS;
      }
      .iw_table_row {
        height: 18px;
      }
      .iw_attribute_name {
        font-weight: bold;
        text-align: right;
      }
      .iw_table_icon {
        text-align: right;
      }
    </style>
  </head>

  <body>

    <div class="hotel-search">
      <div id="findhotels">
        Find hotels in:
      </div>

      <div id="locationField">
        <input id="autocomplete" placeholder="Enter a city" type="text" />
      </div>

      <div id="controls">
        <select id="country">
          <option value="all">All</option>
          <option value="au">Australia</option>
          <option value="br">Brazil</option>
          <option value="ca">Canada</option>
          <option value="fr">France</option>
          <option value="de">Germany</option>
          <option value="mx">Mexico</option>
          <option value="nz">New Zealand</option>
          <option value="it">Italy</option>
          <option value="za">South Africa</option>
          <option value="es">Spain</option>
          <option value="pt">Portugal</option>
          <option value="us" selected>U.S.A.</option>
          <option value="uk">United Kingdom</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div id="map"></div>

    <div id="listing">
      <table id="resultsTable">
        <tbody id="results"></tbody>
      </table>
    </div>

    <div style="display: none">
      <div id="info-content">
        <table>
          <tr id="iw-url-row" class="iw_table_row">
            <td id="iw-icon" class="iw_table_icon"></td>
            <td id="iw-url"></td>
          </tr>
          <tr id="iw-address-row" class="iw_table_row">
            <td class="iw_attribute_name">Address:</td>
            <td id="iw-address"></td>
          </tr>
          <tr id="iw-phone-row" class="iw_table_row">
            <td class="iw_attribute_name">Telephone:</td>
            <td id="iw-phone"></td>
          </tr>
          <tr id="iw-rating-row" class="iw_table_row">
            <td class="iw_attribute_name">Rating:</td>
            <td id="iw-rating"></td>
          </tr>
          <tr id="iw-website-row" class="iw_table_row">
            <td class="iw_attribute_name">Website:</td>
            <td id="iw-website"></td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>

    <script>
      // This example uses the autocomplete feature of the Google Places API.
      // It allows the user to find all hotels in a given place, within a given
      // country. It then displays markers for all the hotels returned,
      // with on-click details for each hotel.

      // This example requires the Places library. Include the libraries=places
      // parameter when you first load the API. For example:
      // <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&libraries=places">

      var map, places, infoWindow;
      var markers = [];
      var autocomplete;
      var countryRestrict = {'country': 'us'};
      var MARKER_PATH = 'https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/images/marker_green';
      var hostnameRegexp = new RegExp('^https?://.+?/');

      var countries = {
        'au': {
          center: {lat: -25.3, lng: 133.8},
          zoom: 4
        },
        'br': {
          center: {lat: -14.2, lng: -51.9},
          zoom: 3
        },
        'ca': {
          center: {lat: 62, lng: -110.0},
          zoom: 3
        },
        'fr': {
          center: {lat: 46.2, lng: 2.2},
          zoom: 5
        },
        'de': {
          center: {lat: 51.2, lng: 10.4},
          zoom: 5
        },
        'mx': {
          center: {lat: 23.6, lng: -102.5},
          zoom: 4
        },
        'nz': {
          center: {lat: -40.9, lng: 174.9},
          zoom: 5
        },
        'it': {
          center: {lat: 41.9, lng: 12.6},
          zoom: 5
        },
        'za': {
          center: {lat: -30.6, lng: 22.9},
          zoom: 5
        },
        'es': {
          center: {lat: 40.5, lng: -3.7},
          zoom: 5
        },
        'pt': {
          center: {lat: 39.4, lng: -8.2},
          zoom: 6
        },
        'us': {
          center: {lat: 37.1, lng: -95.7},
          zoom: 3
        },
        'uk': {
          center: {lat: 54.8, lng: -4.6},
          zoom: 5
        }
      };

      function initMap() {
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          zoom: countries['us'].zoom,
          center: countries['us'].center,
          mapTypeControl: false,
          panControl: false,
          zoomControl: false,
          streetViewControl: false
        });

        infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
          content: document.getElementById('info-content')
        });

        // Create the autocomplete object and associate it with the UI input control.
        // Restrict the search to the default country, and to place type "cities".
        autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
            /** @type {!HTMLInputElement} */ (
                document.getElementById('autocomplete')), {
              types: ['(cities)'],
              componentRestrictions: countryRestrict
            });
        places = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);

        autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', onPlaceChanged);

        // Add a DOM event listener to react when the user selects a country.
        document.getElementById('country').addEventListener(
            'change', setAutocompleteCountry);
      }

      // When the user selects a city, get the place details for the city and
      // zoom the map in on the city.
      function onPlaceChanged() {
        var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
        if (place.geometry) {
          map.panTo(place.geometry.location);
          map.setZoom(15);
          search();
        } else {
          document.getElementById('autocomplete').placeholder = 'Enter a city';
        }
      }

      // Search for hotels in the selected city, within the viewport of the map.
      function search() {
        var search = {
          bounds: map.getBounds(),
          types: ['lodging']
        };

        places.nearbySearch(search, function(results, status) {
          if (status === google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
            clearResults();
            clearMarkers();
            // Create a marker for each hotel found, and
            // assign a letter of the alphabetic to each marker icon.
            for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
              var markerLetter = String.fromCharCode('A'.charCodeAt(0) + (i % 26));
              var markerIcon = MARKER_PATH + markerLetter + '.png';
              // Use marker animation to drop the icons incrementally on the map.
              markers[i] = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: results[i].geometry.location,
                animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
                icon: markerIcon
              });
              // If the user clicks a hotel marker, show the details of that hotel
              // in an info window.
              markers[i].placeResult = results[i];
              google.maps.event.addListener(markers[i], 'click', showInfoWindow);
              setTimeout(dropMarker(i), i * 100);
              addResult(results[i], i);
            }
          }
        });
      }

      function clearMarkers() {
        for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
          if (markers[i]) {
            markers[i].setMap(null);
          }
        }
        markers = [];
      }

      // Set the country restriction based on user input.
      // Also center and zoom the map on the given country.
      function setAutocompleteCountry() {
        var country = document.getElementById('country').value;
        if (country == 'all') {
          autocomplete.setComponentRestrictions({'country': []});
          map.setCenter({lat: 15, lng: 0});
          map.setZoom(2);
        } else {
          autocomplete.setComponentRestrictions({'country': country});
          map.setCenter(countries[country].center);
          map.setZoom(countries[country].zoom);
        }
        clearResults();
        clearMarkers();
      }

      function dropMarker(i) {
        return function() {
          markers[i].setMap(map);
        };
      }

      function addResult(result, i) {
        var results = document.getElementById('results');
        var markerLetter = String.fromCharCode('A'.charCodeAt(0) + (i % 26));
        var markerIcon = MARKER_PATH + markerLetter + '.png';

        var tr = document.createElement('tr');
        tr.style.backgroundColor = (i % 2 === 0 ? '#F0F0F0' : '#FFFFFF');
        tr.onclick = function() {
          google.maps.event.trigger(markers[i], 'click');
        };

        var iconTd = document.createElement('td');
        var nameTd = document.createElement('td');
        var icon = document.createElement('img');
        icon.src = markerIcon;
        icon.setAttribute('class', 'placeIcon');
        icon.setAttribute('className', 'placeIcon');
        var name = document.createTextNode(result.name);
        iconTd.appendChild(icon);
        nameTd.appendChild(name);
        tr.appendChild(iconTd);
        tr.appendChild(nameTd);
        results.appendChild(tr);
      }

      function clearResults() {
        var results = document.getElementById('results');
        while (results.childNodes[0]) {
          results.removeChild(results.childNodes[0]);
        }
      }

      // Get the place details for a hotel. Show the information in an info window,
      // anchored on the marker for the hotel that the user selected.
      function showInfoWindow() {
        var marker = this;
        places.getDetails({placeId: marker.placeResult.place_id},
            function(place, status) {
              if (status !== google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
                return;
              }
              infoWindow.open(map, marker);
              buildIWContent(place);
            });
      }

      // Load the place information into the HTML elements used by the info window.
      function buildIWContent(place) {
        document.getElementById('iw-icon').innerHTML = '<img class="hotelIcon" ' +
            'src="' + place.icon + '"/>';
        document.getElementById('iw-url').innerHTML = '<b><a href="' + place.url +
            '">' + place.name + '</a></b>';
        document.getElementById('iw-address').textContent = place.vicinity;

        if (place.formatted_phone_number) {
          document.getElementById('iw-phone-row').style.display = '';
          document.getElementById('iw-phone').textContent =
              place.formatted_phone_number;
        } else {
          document.getElementById('iw-phone-row').style.display = 'none';
        }

        // Assign a five-star rating to the hotel, using a black star ('&#10029;')
        // to indicate the rating the hotel has earned, and a white star ('&#10025;')
        // for the rating points not achieved.
        if (place.rating) {
          var ratingHtml = '';
          for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            if (place.rating < (i + 0.5)) {
              ratingHtml += '&#10025;';
            } else {
              ratingHtml += '&#10029;';
            }
          document.getElementById('iw-rating-row').style.display = '';
          document.getElementById('iw-rating').innerHTML = ratingHtml;
          }
        } else {
          document.getElementById('iw-rating-row').style.display = 'none';
        }

        // The regexp isolates the first part of the URL (domain plus subdomain)
        // to give a short URL for displaying in the info window.
        if (place.website) {
          var fullUrl = place.website;
          var website = hostnameRegexp.exec(place.website);
          if (website === null) {
            website = 'http://' + place.website + '/';
            fullUrl = website;
          }
          document.getElementById('iw-website-row').style.display = '';
          document.getElementById('iw-website').textContent = website;
        } else {
          document.getElementById('iw-website-row').style.display = 'none';
        }
      }
    </script>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&libraries=places&callback=initMap"
        async defer></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

This however allows me to perform the search alone on a category ("lodging" in this case).

I would like to search for places on more than one category (In my case I entered: Lodging, Restaurant and Stadium then I changed the "search" function like this:

```
function search() {
        var types = ["lodging", "restaurant", "stadium"];
        var FirstEsecution = true;

        types.forEach(type => {
          var search = {
            bounds: map.getBounds(),
            types: [type]
          };

          places.nearbySearch(search, function(results, status) {
            if (status === google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
              if (FirstEsecution) {
                clearResults();
                clearMarkers();
                FirstEsecution = false;
              }
              // Create a marker for each hotel found, and
              // assign a letter of the alphabetic to each marker icon.
              for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
                var markerLetter = String.fromCharCode(
                  "A".charCodeAt(0) + (i % 26)
                );
                var markerIcon = MARKER_PATH + markerLetter + ".png";
                // Use marker animation to drop the icons incrementally on the map.
                markers[i] = new google.maps.Marker({
                  position: results[i].geometry.location,
                  animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
                  icon: markerIcon
                });
                // If the user clicks a hotel marker, show the details of that hotel
                // in an info window.
                markers[i].placeResult = results[i];
                google.maps.event.addListener(
                  markers[i],
                  "click",
                  showInfoWindow
                );
                setTimeout(dropMarker(i), i * 100);
                addResult(results[i], i);
              }
            }
          });
        });
      }
```

Now I have a problem, it shows all the markers on the map correctly (20 maximum for each category, and each marker is associated with a letter). So far so good, except that every time the cycle starts on a new "category type", start again to associate a letter on the marker starting from A and then I find myself markers with the same letter, and also when in the results list I click on a name opens pop up on the wrong marker because the correct marker is not recognized as there are more than one marker with the same letter. Do you have any suggestions to solve the problem? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`types` as an array was deprecated.  It only allows one type (the new field is called [type](https://developers-dot-devsite-v2-prod.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/places-service#PlaceSearchRequest.type)).  To get responses for multiple types you need to make multiple requests.

from the [documentation](https://developers-dot-devsite-v2-prod.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/releases#21-december-2015)

> **21 December 2015**
>   Changes:
>   The interface for text search requests has changed. **The types parameter is deprecated as of March 1, 2016, replaced by a new type parameter which only supports one type per search request**. Additionally, the establishment, food, and grocery_or_supermarket types will no longer be supported as search parameters (however these types may still be returned in the results of a search). Requests using the legacy types parameter will be supported until March 1, 2017, after which all text searches must use the new implementation.

One option would be to handle the types as different arrays, keeping the type available in the callback function using function closure.

```
    places.nearbySearch(search, (function(type) {
      return function(results, status) {
        if (status === google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
          console.log("processing " + results.length + " for type=" + type);
          if (FirstEsecution) {
            clearResults();
            clearMarkers();
            FirstEsecution = false;
          }
          // Create a marker for each hotel found, and
          // assign a letter of the alphabetic to each marker icon.
          for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
            var markerLetter = String.fromCharCode(
              "A".charCodeAt(0) + (i % 26)
            );
            var markerIcon = MARKER_PATH + markerLetter + ".png";
            // Use marker animation to drop the icons incrementally on the map.
            if (!markers[type])
              markers[type] = [];
            markers[type][i] = new google.maps.Marker({
              position: results[i].geometry.location,
              animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
              icon: {url:customIcons[type].icon,
              labelOrigin: new google.maps.Point(15,10) },
              label: {text: markerLetter,
                }
            });
            // If the user clicks a hotel marker, show the details of that hotel
            // in an info window.
            markers[type][i].placeResult = results[i];
            google.maps.event.addListener(
              markers[type][i],
              "click",
              showInfoWindow
            );
            setTimeout(dropMarker(i), i * 100);
            addResult(results[i], i, type);
          }
        } else console.log("no results for " + type + ": " + status)
      };
    })(type))
  })
```

[proof of concept fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/w3oLtg4f/3/)

[image: screenshot of resulting map]

**code snippet:**

```js
// This example uses the autocomplete feature of the Google Places API.
// It allows the user to find all hotels in a given place, within a given
// country. It then displays markers for all the hotels returned,
// with on-click details for each hotel.

// This example requires the Places library. Include the libraries=places
// parameter when you first load the API. For example:
// <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&libraries=places">
var types = ["lodging", "restaurant", "stadium"];
var map, places, infoWindow;
var markers = [];
var autocomplete;
var countryRestrict = {
  'country': 'us'
};
var MARKER_PATH = 'https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/images/marker_green';
var MARKER_BASEPATH = 'https://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/micons/';
var customIcons = {
  lodging: {
    icon: MARKER_BASEPATH + "red.png"
  },
  restaurant: {
    icon: MARKER_BASEPATH + "green.png"
  },
  stadium: {
    icon: MARKER_BASEPATH + "blue.png"
  }
};
var hostnameRegexp = new RegExp('^https?://.+?/');

var countries = {
  'us': {
    center: {
      lat: 37.1,
      lng: -95.7
    },
    zoom: 3
  },
};

function initMap() {
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: countries['us'].zoom,
    center: countries['us'].center,
    mapTypeControl: false,
    panControl: false,
    zoomControl: false,
    streetViewControl: false
  });

  infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content: document.getElementById('info-content')
  });

  // Create the autocomplete object and associate it with the UI input control.
  // Restrict the search to the default country, and to place type "cities".
  autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
    /** @type {!HTMLInputElement} */
    (
      document.getElementById('autocomplete')), {
      types: ['(cities)'],
      componentRestrictions: countryRestrict
    });
  places = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);

  autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', onPlaceChanged);

  // Add a DOM event listener to react when the user selects a country.
  document.getElementById('country').addEventListener(
    'change', setAutocompleteCountry);
}

// When the user selects a city, get the place details for the city and
// zoom the map in on the city.
function onPlaceChanged() {
  var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
  if (place.geometry) {
    map.panTo(place.geometry.location);
    map.setZoom(15);
    search();
  } else {
    document.getElementById('autocomplete').placeholder = 'Enter a city';
  }
}

// Search for hotels in the selected city, within the viewport of the map.
function search() {
  var FirstEsecution = true;

  types.forEach(type => {
    var search = {
      bounds: map.getBounds(),
      types: [type]
    };

    places.nearbySearch(search, (function(type) {
      return function(results, status) {
        if (status === google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
          console.log("processing " + results.length + " for type=" + type);
          if (FirstEsecution) {
            clearResults();
            clearMarkers();
            FirstEsecution = false;
          }
          // Create a marker for each hotel found, and
          // assign a letter of the alphabetic to each marker icon.
          for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
            var markerLetter = String.fromCharCode(
              "A".charCodeAt(0) + (i % 26)
            );
            var markerIcon = MARKER_PATH + markerLetter + ".png";
            // Use marker animation to drop the icons incrementally on the map.
            if (!markers[type])
              markers[type] = [];
            markers[type][i] = new google.maps.Marker({
              position: results[i].geometry.location,
              animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
              icon: {
                url: customIcons[type].icon,
                labelOrigin: new google.maps.Point(15, 10)
              },
              label: {
                text: markerLetter,
              }
            });
            // If the user clicks a hotel marker, show the details of that hotel
            // in an info window.
            markers[type][i].placeResult = results[i];
            google.maps.event.addListener(
              markers[type][i],
              "click",
              showInfoWindow
            );
            setTimeout(dropMarker(i), i * 100);
            addResult(results[i], i, type);
          }
        } else console.log("no results for " + type + ": " + status)
      };
    })(type))
  })
}

function clearMarkers() {
  for (var j = 0; j < types.length; j++) {
    type = types[j];
    if (markers[type]) {
      for (var i = 0; i < markers[type].length; i++) {
        if (markers[type][i]) {
          markers[type][i].setMap(null);
        }
      }
      markers[type] = [];
    }
  }
}
// Set the country restriction based on user input.
// Also center and zoom the map on the given country.
function setAutocompleteCountry() {
  var country = document.getElementById('country').value;
  if (country == 'all') {
    autocomplete.setComponentRestrictions({
      'country': []
    });
    map.setCenter({
      lat: 15,
      lng: 0
    });
    map.setZoom(2);
  } else {
    autocomplete.setComponentRestrictions({
      'country': country
    });
    map.setCenter(countries[country].center);
    map.setZoom(countries[country].zoom);
  }
  clearResults();
  clearMarkers();
}

function dropMarker(i) {
  return function() {
    for (var j = 0; j < types.length; j++) {
      type = types[j];
      if (markers[type] && markers[type].length > i) {
        console.log("drop " + type + " " + i);
        markers[type][i].setMap(map);
      };
    }
  }
}

function addResult(result, i, type) {
  var results = document.getElementById('results');
  var markerLetter = String.fromCharCode('A'.charCodeAt(0) + (i % 26));
  var markerIcon = MARKER_PATH + markerLetter + '.png';

  var tr = document.createElement('tr');
  tr.style.backgroundColor = (i % 2 === 0 ? '#F0F0F0' : '#FFFFFF');
  tr.onclick = function() {
    google.maps.event.trigger(markers[type][i], 'click');
  };

  var iconTd = document.createElement('td');
  var nameTd = document.createElement('td');
  var icon = document.createElement('img');
  icon.src = markerIcon;
  icon.setAttribute('class', 'placeIcon');
  icon.setAttribute('className', 'placeIcon');
  var name = document.createTextNode(type + ":" + result.name);
  iconTd.appendChild(icon);
  nameTd.appendChild(name);
  tr.appendChild(iconTd);
  tr.appendChild(nameTd);
  results.appendChild(tr);
}

function clearResults() {
  var results = document.getElementById('results');
  while (results.childNodes[0]) {
    results.removeChild(results.childNodes[0]);
  }
}

// Get the place details for a hotel. Show the information in an info window,
// anchored on the marker for the hotel that the user selected.
function showInfoWindow() {
  var marker = this;
  places.getDetails({
      placeId: marker.placeResult.place_id
    },
    function(place, status) {
      if (status !== google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
        return;
      }
      infoWindow.open(map, marker);
      buildIWContent(place);
    });
}

// Load the place information into the HTML elements used by the info window.
function buildIWContent(place) {
  document.getElementById('iw-icon').innerHTML = '<img class="hotelIcon" ' +
    'src="' + place.icon + '"/>';
  document.getElementById('iw-url').innerHTML = '<b><a href="' + place.url +
    '">' + place.name + '</a></b>';
  document.getElementById('iw-address').textContent = place.vicinity;

  if (place.formatted_phone_number) {
    document.getElementById('iw-phone-row').style.display = '';
    document.getElementById('iw-phone').textContent =
      place.formatted_phone_number;
  } else {
    document.getElementById('iw-phone-row').style.display = 'none';
  }

  // Assign a five-star rating to the hotel, using a black star ('&#10029;')
  // to indicate the rating the hotel has earned, and a white star ('&#10025;')
  // for the rating points not achieved.
  if (place.rating) {
    var ratingHtml = '';
    for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
      if (place.rating < (i + 0.5)) {
        ratingHtml += '&#10025;';
      } else {
        ratingHtml += '&#10029;';
      }
      document.getElementById('iw-rating-row').style.display = '';
      document.getElementById('iw-rating').innerHTML = ratingHtml;
    }
  } else {
    document.getElementById('iw-rating-row').style.display = 'none';
  }

  // The regexp isolates the first part of the URL (domain plus subdomain)
  // to give a short URL for displaying in the info window.
  if (place.website) {
    var fullUrl = place.website;
    var website = hostnameRegexp.exec(place.website);
    if (website === null) {
      website = 'http://' + place.website + '/';
      fullUrl = website;
    }
    document.getElementById('iw-website-row').style.display = '';
    document.getElementById('iw-website').textContent = website;
  } else {
    document.getElementById('iw-website-row').style.display = 'none';
  }
}
```

```css
/* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
       * element that contains the map. */

#map {
  height: 100%;
}


/* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  padding: 0 !important;
}

table {
  font-size: 12px;
}

.hotel-search {
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  background: #fff;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 440px;
  z-index: 1;
}

#map {
  margin-top: 40px;
  width: 440px;
}

#listing {
  position: absolute;
  width: 200px;
  height: 470px;
  overflow: auto;
  left: 442px;
  top: 0px;
  cursor: pointer;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

#findhotels {
  font-size: 14px;
}

#locationField {
  -webkit-box-flex: 1 1 190px;
  -ms-flex: 1 1 190px;
  flex: 1 1 190px;
  margin: 0 8px;
}

#controls {
  -webkit-box-flex: 1 1 140px;
  -ms-flex: 1 1 140px;
  flex: 1 1 140px;
}

#autocomplete {
  width: 100%;
}

#country {
  width: 100%;
}

.placeIcon {
  width: 20px;
  height: 34px;
  margin: 4px;
}

.hotelIcon {
  width: 24px;
  height: 24px;
}

#resultsTable {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 240px;
}

#rating {
  font-size: 13px;
  font-family: Arial Unicode MS;
}

.iw_table_row {
  height: 18px;
}

.iw_attribute_name {
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: right;
}

.iw_table_icon {
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="hotel-search">
  <div id="findhotels">
    Find hotels in:
  </div>

  <div id="locationField">
    <input id="autocomplete" placeholder="Enter a city" type="text" value="Nebraska City, NE" />
  </div>

  <div id="controls">
    <select id="country">
      <option value="all">All</option>
      <option value="au">Australia</option>
      <option value="br">Brazil</option>
      <option value="ca">Canada</option>
      <option value="fr">France</option>
      <option value="de">Germany</option>
      <option value="mx">Mexico</option>
      <option value="nz">New Zealand</option>
      <option value="it">Italy</option>
      <option value="za">South Africa</option>
      <option value="es">Spain</option>
      <option value="pt">Portugal</option>
      <option value="us" selected>U.S.A.</option>
      <option value="uk">United Kingdom</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="map"></div>

<div id="listing">
  <table id="resultsTable">
    <tbody id="results"></tbody>
  </table>
</div>

<div style="display: none">
  <div id="info-content">
    <table>
      <tr id="iw-url-row" class="iw_table_row">
        <td id="iw-icon" class="iw_table_icon"></td>
        <td id="iw-url"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr id="iw-address-row" class="iw_table_row">
        <td class="iw_attribute_name">Address:</td>
        <td id="iw-address"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr id="iw-phone-row" class="iw_table_row">
        <td class="iw_attribute_name">Telephone:</td>
        <td id="iw-phone"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr id="iw-rating-row" class="iw_table_row">
        <td class="iw_attribute_name">Rating:</td>
        <td id="iw-rating"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr id="iw-website-row" class="iw_table_row">
        <td class="iw_attribute_name">Website:</td>
        <td id="iw-website"></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk&libraries=places&callback=initMap" async defer></script>
```

Comment: Hi @geocodezip were you able to take the example? I just can't get the result . Thanks and sorry for disturbing you.

Comment: Thanks @geocodezip, the code works in https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/w3oLtg4f/3/. But if I put it on my wordpress page it won't work for me. I added above the code I entered on the wordpress page.